# Is it possible to expose a USB UPS via SNMPD?

Tags: usb, snmp, ups, nut

I have a Rack Mount Cyberpower UPS I'd like to be able to monitor with LibreNMS. It only connects via USB.

Is it possible to have the Ubuntu Server running SNMPD expose the UPS MIBs?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, but snmpd likely lacks native support for UPS and you would have to bridge this with external scripts -- f.e. using https://github.com/luizluca/nut-snmpagent

Network UPS Tools had a project to add SNMP agent capability, but apparently it was never completed.